# Assertion failed when trying to copy part of OpenCV Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

Im trying to copy a part of Mat to other matrix, this is my code:

```
Mat OCRprocess;
OCRImage(Rect(plates[i].x, plates[i].y, plates[i].width, plates[i].height)).copyTo(OCRprocess);
```

ROI: x: 1200 y: 608 w: 356 h: 89 (data from cascade detector)

This is return:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x
>   + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\
>   core\src\matrix.cpp, line 495

Comment: I think you just need to get familiar with your debugger...

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `OcrProcess` of the same size of the rectangles before calling `copyTo`:

```
// Your rect
Rect r(plates[i].x, plates[i].y, plates[i].width, plates[i].height);
// Initialize the destination image
Mat OCRprocess(r.height, r.width, OCRImage.type());
// Copy
OCRImage(Rect).copyTo(OCRprocess);
```

Or, more simply, using `clone`:

```
Mat OCRprocess = OCRImage(Rect(plates[i].x, plates[i].y, plates[i].width, plates[i].height)).clone();
```

Comment: Tested both and still same problem.

Comment: Then you have also another problem: your rectangle goes out of the image boundaries.